# Can you lock an Oracle sequence?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Is it possible to lock an Oracle sequence so any session trying to use nextval on it blocks until I'm done with my script?

I'll explain what I'm doing in case there's a different way.  I'm preparing a schema to do bidirectional replication with streams.  I want to make sure all the primary key sequences produce unique values.  I do this by incrementing the sequence by 1 until the last digit is 1 and then change the increment to 100.  On the other server I do the same until the last digit is 2.  That way server 1 always produces primary keys XXXXX01 and server 2 XXXXX02.

The problem is this is a 24x7 database, and I can't stop all activity while I'm adjusting the sequences.  If I can get an exclusive lock for a short time I can do it reliably.

Comment: You can current value of the sequence to be the max value.

Comment: In that situation the Proper solution is usually to use a GUID as the key rather than an incrementing index, you lose a little in size as the GUID is almost certainly larger than your key field but provides almost total safety against exactly this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot lock a sequence. You could try to re-create the sequences in the required status. It will cause a problem for a short while.

Comment: Thanks.  I think just try to do it during a quiet time and hopefully get the sequence set before another session hits it.  If I don't get them all, I can always run the script again.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest possible solution (in my opinion) is to use odd numbers for server 1 and even numbers for server 2. This also removes the need for serialization.

```
create sequence server1_seq increment by 2 start with 1;
create sequence server2_seq increment by 2 start with 2;
```

This would produce a series of values like:

```
Server 1  Server 2
--------  --------
   1          2
   3          4
   5          6 
   7          8
   9         10
```

This solution can further be extended to handle more than two servers by using larger increments (and different starting values for each server).

Having said that, do **NOT** use this approach if you intend to add more servers over time. You would have to take all databases offline and rebuild the tables from scratch.

Comment: The problem is not how to set the sequences.  It's trying to set them to the right values on a live database.

Comment: @JOTN, ah, sorry I missunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the idea of using separate non-overlapping sequences as Ronnis has suggested.

Another option to consider is a composite primary key.

1. If you're able to add a column to the data model, you add an identifier that is set differently depending on which server the process is running on.
2. If you cannot add a column, you could instead change the column data type to VARCHAR2, and set it as a composite; e.g. on server 1, you would concatenate '1-' to the sequence value, e.g. '1-103450' would therefore not conflict with '2-103450' generated on server 2.

Either way, this doesn't suffer from any problems with adding more servers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to temporarily stop sessions from getting a value from the sequence, you could just revoke access to it. Unless, of course, your users are logging in as the owner of the sequence.

```
REVOKE SELECT ON mysequence FROM username;
```

Note: it's not a lock per se; instead of waiting, they'll get an Oracle error (invalid identifier, I think).

Answer (score -1):

It seems you actually can lock a sequence.

```
SELECT SEQ_NAME.nextval FROM dual FOR UPDATE [NOWAIT];
```

Tested on Oracle 11 XE. Also have a look at https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20181432/lock-wait-on-sequence.html and https://geraldonit.com/oracle/database/oracle-database-locktypes/.